# apache returns 404 even after mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

I am using apache mod_rewrite for the first time.
I want http://example.com/anything/after/this to be transformed as http://example.com/storage-server/index.php?id=/anything/after/this

I have written following lines to apache's httpd.conf file

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /storage-server/index.php?id=$1
```

But I am getting 404 message saying that this file doesn't exist. I have enabled the mod_rewrite so that is not issue. I think something is preventing this URL to be rewritten....
any idea???

UPDATE:: 
All things are solved. All above mentioned settings should be entered into /etc/apache2/sites-enables/000-default file..

SOLVED

UPDATE:::

I have just tried extremely simple rewrite rule. I have created test1.html and test2.html files in my web server root. Then i wrote following rule in my httpd.conf file

```
RewriteRule ^test1\.html$ test2.html
```

When i visit test1.html the browser still shows test1.html file instead of test2.html/ Please help.. I am having this trouble since last 3 days... sick of it ..:-(

Answer (score 0):

You write that you want it to redirect to http://example.com/index.php?id=/anything/after/this but you're redirecting to http://example.com/storage-server/index.php?id=/anything/after/this. Could that be it?

Comment: a.k.a. note that you're still redirecting to documents relative to document root.

Comment: sorry... I want to redirect to <http://example.com/storage-server/index.php?id=/anything/after/this> is there any mistake in my rewrite rule???

Answer (score 0):

ensure that the following line in your Apache's **httpd.conf** is not commented out

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so